# Calling an Oracle stored procedure in Informatica Cloud postprocessing command

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, informatica-cloud

I have an Informatica data synchronization task that creates a table in Oracle. I am trying to include a call to an Oracle stored procedure in the postprocessing command of Informatica Cloud that will update a variety of tables at the completion of the task. The procedure that I am trying to call is in the same schema as the target of the synchronization task. The procedure runs correctly when I run it directly in Oracle SQL Developer, but I can't get it to run via Informatica Cloud. I know I'm not using the right syntax to make the call, but these are some examples that I have tried so far:

```
BEGIN
(PROCEDURE_NAME)
END;

CALL(PROCEDURE_NAME);

EXEC(PROCEDURE_NAME);

PROCEDURE_NAME;
```

Would designing a mapping in Informatica Cloud help me with this? Or is there a prefix that I should be appending to the stored procedure call, even though the procedure is in the same schema as the target of the task?

Answer (score 0):

None of these options will work in Synchronisation task. Call (procedure_name); will work in Mappings which is the easiest way to do it

In Synchronisation task you need to create a batch file to run a SQL script. The script has to contain the connection details.
    Example:
           connect user/password@
            exec (procedure_name);
            disconnect;
            exit SQL.SQLCODE

SQL.SQLCODE is used so that it will commit all the transactions.

After that, it will be necessary to use a .bat to run the above sql script using sqlplus client.
        Example:
         cd \bin
         call cmd.exe /C "sqlplus /nolog < {path to sql script created in step 
         2}\filename.sql"
         exit /b 0;